# Manually modifying model property values in vapor 4 response

Tags: swift, vapor, server-side-swift, vapor-fluent

I have a vapor 4 application. I do a query from database for getting some items and I want to perform some manual calculation based on the returned values before finishing the request. here a sample code of what I am trying to achieve.

```swift
final class Todo: Model, Content {

    static var schema: String = "todos"

    @ID(custom: .id)
    var id: Int?

    @Field(key: "title")
    var title: String

    var someValue: Int?

}

/// Allows `Todo` to be used as a dynamic migration.
struct CreateTodo: Migration {
    func prepare(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema(Todo.schema)
            .field("id", .int, .identifier(auto: true))
            .field("title", .string, .required)
            .create()
    }

    func revert(on database: Database) -> EventLoopFuture<Void> {
        database.schema(Todo.schema).delete()
    }
}
```

```swift
final class TodoController:RouteCollection{

    func boot(routes: RoutesBuilder) throws {

        routes.get("tmp", use: temp)
    }

    func temp(_ req:Request) throws -> EventLoopFuture<[Todo]> {

        Todo.query(on: req.db).all().map { todos in

            todos.map {
                $0.someValue = (0...10).randomElement()!
                return $0
            }
        }
    }

}
```

**The problem is that those manual changes, aren't available in response. In this case `someValue` property.**

Thanks.

```js
[
    {
        "title": "item 1",
        "id": 1
    },
    {
        "title": "item 2",
        "id": 2
    }
]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem you're hitting is that `Model`s override the `Codable` implementations. This allows you to do things like passing around parents and not adding children etc.

However, this breaks your case. What you should do, is create a new type if you want to return a `Todo` with another field that isn't stored in the database, something like:

```swift
struct TodoResponse: Content {
  let id: Int
  let title: String
  let someValue: Int
}
```

And then convert from your database type to your response type in your route handler (this is a pretty common pattern and the recommended way to do it in Vapor)

Comment: I'm trying to do something similar, but specific to integration with a Leaf template rather than in the API context. In this case, I'm a little fuzzy on the correct/swift-y approach here. The struct you're recommending here would belong to the Model or the ModelController or the WebController ?

Comment: I'd just put it in a folder called `LeafModels`